# WSDL: Error with arrays

Tags: c#, xsd, wsdl

I have a WSDL from which I create the objects in c#

```
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfPlentysoapresponsemessage">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:PlentySoapResponseMessage" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" nillable="true"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

The resulting code is

```
private PlentySoapResponseMessage[] itemField;
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("PlentySoapResponseMessage", typeof(PlentySoapResponseMessage), IsNullable = false)]
public PlentySoapResponseMessage[] item {
  get {
    return this.itemField;
  }
  set {
    this.itemField = value;
  }
}
```

I get errors from c# that deserializing is not working
The reason I found is that the array is leading to a problem since when removing there is a single item and no error

Here the message

> [System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException] = {"Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation \"GetAuthentificationToken\"."}

Server stack trace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the C# API, ending with c

Please change
your-shop.de/plenty/api/soap/version114/
to
your-shop.de/plenty/api/soap/version114c/
and generate new C# classes with the C# WSDL
your-shop.de/plenty/api/soap/version114c/?xml